# Как задать блоку элемент массива JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Если быть более точным, то у меня имеется блок данных:

```
    <div class="rowwrapper2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
```

и массив в JS:

```
var Cards = [
{
    img: "css/images/cards/1.png",
    name: "10k",
},
{
    img: "css/images/cards/2.png",
    name: "10b",
},
{
    img: "css/images/cards/3.png",
    name: "10c",
},
{
    img: "css/images/cards/4.png",
    name: "10b",
},];
```

Как сделать так, чтобы всем блокам `<div>` присвоить случайное значение массива, то есть `background-image` установить из `img` и чтобы этот блок характеризовался `name`?
Или можно это сделать каким-то более адекватным способом?

Comment: >>и чтобы этот блок характеризовался name<< это как?

Comment: Может быть я не совсем корректно выражусь,но по name я бы хотел сравнивать блоки, то есть проверять их по этому атрибуту,равны ли они

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Cards = [{
    img: "http://www.2fons.ru/pic/201503/1280x1024/2fons.ru-84831.jpg",
    name: "10k",
  },
  {
    img: "https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/11/18/443734993463506/cvety-makro-xoroshee-kachestvo-krasota.jpg",
    name: "10b",
  },
  {
    img: "http://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/40/401119-svetik_1152x864.jpg",
    name: "10c",
  },
  {
    img: "http://ru.hdwall365.com/wallpapers/1602/Chrysanthemums-orchids-gerbera-colorful-flowers_2560x1600_wallpaper.jpg",
    name: "10b",
  },
];

var cardsCopy = Array.from(Cards);
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".rowwrapper2 div");

for(var div of divs) {
    var ran = GetRan(cardsCopy.length);
    div.style.background = `url(${cardsCopy[ran].img})`;
    div.setAttribute("name",cardsCopy[ran].name);
    cardsCopy.splice(ran,1);
}

function GetRan(max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

```css
.rowwrapper2 div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowwrapper2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```